# How can I make a face detection on a captured photo android?

Tags: android, camera, photo, face-detection, image-capture

I am trying to detect a face on a photo that has been taken automatically but it doesnt work. After i capture the picture i send it to an ImageView and then i try to take it from their and make face detection. But there is the error, the bitmap requires R.drawble and i give R.id. I dont know what to use 
Im a newbie

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int cameraID = 0;
public static boolean isBlack = true;
public static ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    Button btfront=(Button) findViewById(R.id.frontButton);
    btfront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onFrontClick(v);
            facedetection(v);


        }

    });
}

public void onFrontClick(View v){
    RadioButton rdbBlack = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdb_black);
    if(rdbBlack.isChecked()){
        isBlack = true;
    }else{
        isBlack = false;
    }
    cameraID = 1;
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraView.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 999);



}

public void onBackClick(View v){
    RadioButton rdbBlack = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdb_black);
    if(rdbBlack.isChecked()){
        isBlack = true;
    }else{
        isBlack = false;
    }
    cameraID = 0;
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraView.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 999);
}
public void facedetection(View v)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable=true;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            R.id.imgView,
            options);
    Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
    myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    FaceDetector faceDetector = new
            FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .build();
    if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("Could not set up the face detector!").show();
        return;
    }

    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
    SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);
    for(int j=0; j<faces.size(); j++) {
        Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(j);
        float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
        float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
        float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
        float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
        tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
    }
    image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));
}
```

}

here is the class that i capture the photo

```
public class CameraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener{
        private static final String TAG = "CameraTest";
        Camera mCamera;
        boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.cameraview);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blankImage);

        if(MainActivity.isBlack)
            img.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        else
            img.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (data != null){
                //Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                //mIntent.putExtra("image",imageData);

                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mPreviewRunning = false;
                mCamera.release();

                 try{
                     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                     Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opts);
                     bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false);
                     int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                     int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                     int newWidth = 300;
                     int newHeight = 300;

                     // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
                     float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                     float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

                     // createa matrix for the manipulation
                     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                     // resize the bit map
                     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                     // rotate the Bitmap
                     matrix.postRotate(-90);
                     Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                             width, height, matrix, true);
                     MainActivity.image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                 }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                //StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,"ImageName");
                //setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                setResult(585);
                finish();
            }       
        }
    };

    protected void onResume(){
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @TargetApi(9)
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open(MainActivity.cameraID);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
        if (mPreviewRunning){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(300, 300);

        if(MainActivity.cameraID == 0){
            String stringFlashMode = p.getFlashMode();
            if (stringFlashMode.equals("torch"))
                    p.setFlashMode("on"); // Light is set off, flash is set to normal 'on' mode
            else
                    p.setFlashMode("torch");
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }catch (Exception e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        //mCamera.stopPreview();
        //mPreviewRunning = false;
        //mCamera.release();
    }

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lefteris if its conversion you are looking at

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
```